# bash cd autocompletion without alias?

Tags: bash, autocomplete, alias, cd

How do I use `cd` such that when I type 'cd wo' and there is only one directory starting with 'wo' (say, 'work'), that cd cd's into work? I think I remember doing this and I did not make a custom alias.

Comment: `bash` has a `cdspell` option, although it is not quite powerful enough to fully complete the directory name. It can handle a single missing character ("wok"), a single extra letter ("worka"), or a transposed pair ("wrok" instead of "work"), but nothing more complex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Bash, pressing the "tab" key will autocomplete paths and directories.

So `cd wo[tab]` becomes `cd work`.

[More on other forms of Bash autocompletion here.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-line_completion)

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking for [bash-completion](http://anonscm.debian.org/gitweb/?p=bash-completion/bash-completion.git;a=blob_plain;f=README).